# How to calculate/get user internet bandwidth speed on flutter app

Tags: networking, flutter

I am currently working on Flutter app. I have to implement Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP(DASH) protocol for video streaming on my app. For that I have to know the current internet bandwidth speed of the user, so I can stream video quality accordingly. So is there anyway I can calculate user internet speed?

I have seen Connectivity package but it can only identify if user is connected to internet(Wifi or mobile data), but not the speed of the user's internet.

Maybe there are some other packages for flutter where I can have the user's internet speed.

Comment: It looks like there is no way to check that but you can upload/download some test data routinely ( 500KB - 1 MB) and measure the time it took.

Comment: You are not actually asking about bandwidth. You are asking about throughput. Bandwidth is how many bits per second a link can transmit, and this is fixed for a medium/protocol. For example a 100Base-TX (100 Mb ethernet on UTP), link the bandwidth is always 100 Mbps, but the throughput on that link can vary based on the protocols used above that, the end-device processing speeds, etc.

Comment: hey, @Hassan Afzal did you find any solution.

Comment: Is it possible to create an Internet speed meter app using flutter?

Comment: @JigarFumakiya No I still did not find any solution. I shifted my scope to Web to complete my project.

Comment: any find solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [internet_speed_test](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test) plugin  could be used to test the user internet speed.

Here is an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test/example) from the package:

[image]